# C++ error: declaration of ‘~Destructor’ as member of ‘Class’

Tags: c++, g++

I compile using `g++ -Wall -Werror *.cpp` and get the error:

`ConcreteCharArray.h:21:15: error: declaration of ‘~CharArray’ as member of ‘ConcreteCharArray’`

Concrete implementation:

```
class ConcreteCharArray: public CharArray
{
private:
    char * charArray;
public:
   ~CharArray() {
      delete[] string;
   }
};
```

Virtual class:

```
class CharArray
{
public:
   virtual ~CharArray() {};
};
```

Comment: rename to ~ConcreteCharArray

Comment: The destuctor needs to be the same name as the class so `~CharArray` should be `~ConcreteCharArray`.

Answer (score 4):

Declaring a member named `~CharArray` inside a class named `ConcreteCharArray` is simply illegal, which is what the compiler is telling you. The presence of `~` indicated that you are declaring a destructor, and the name of destructor must match the name of the class.

Destructors are *special* member functions. One of their special properties is that in order to override the virtual destructor of base class, you don't have to match the name of that destructor in the derived class (as you'd normally do with ordinary member functions). The compiler will match the destructors to each other automatically, even though their names are different. This is easy to do, since each class has one and only one destructor.

So, if you want to declare a destructor in class `ConcreteCharArray` you have to call that destructor `~ConcreteCharArray`. There are no other options. Even though the name of derived destructor is different from the name of base destructor, the derived destructor will be treated as virtual and will override the base one.

Comment: Well, only thing is that destructors are not overridden. If you implement both destructors, both are called, beginning with the child destructor.

Comment: @opatut: They *are* overriden. Polymorphic calls to virtual destructors are dispatched in accordance with usual rules for virtual dispatch. "The only thing" here is that derived destructor always *implicitly* calls base and member destructors, but that's a completely different story. It is *internal* destructor behavior, which does not in any way pertain to overriding.

Comment: Oh my, I am not worthy of giving C++ inheritance stuff advice :( But really, "override" in natural language means "original stuff is gone" which definitely is not the case here (implicit call of said "original stuff"), so you can't actually get rid of a virtual parent destructor. I would definitely not call this a typical case of overriding, although, technically, it is.

Comment: @opatut: As it happens, a term might have slightly different meaning between C++ language nomenclature and general OOP nomenclature. I understand what you are talking about. But even with ordinary functions, you can always explicitly call the base version of a polymorphic function from the derived version of that function. This would reproduce (or closely match) the behavior of the destructor. Still, in C++ terminology, the derived function *overrides* the base one and everything else is just internal behavior of the overrider. In general OOP world it might have a different name though...

Comment: @opatut: This, BTW, opens a whole new can of largely philosophical questions. For example, if I write a virtual derived class's function `foo()`, which calls the base class's function `foo()` only in 50% of cases (say, based on random number generator), does the derived `foo()` override the base `foo()` or not? :)

Comment: Well, yeah. And if I duplicate the code into the derived class, what then? But really, the behaviour is different, so I'd call it overridden. But in natural language terms, a destructor is rather... "extended"?? Good thing we do have a defined terminology for this :)